# How to make an image roll

Tags: javascript, html, image, storage

I want to make a next-prev type web comic image gallery like that of [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com) or [smbc](http://www.smbc-comics.com/)

The following is the first idea to pop into my head.

**HTML:**

```
 <h1>Oscars 2015</h1>
 <button id="prev" onclick="prev(); return false;" disabled>PREVIOUS</button>
 <button id="next" onclick="next(); return false;">NEXT</button>
 <h3>(<span id="num">#</span>) <span id='title'>title</span></h3>
 <img id="comic"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var img = [
 ["http://i.imgur.com/B1YclC5.jpg", "Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance) won Best Picture."],
 ["http://i.imgur.com/XjAdinX.jpg", "Eddie Redmayne won Best Actor in a Leading Role for his role in The Theory of Everything."],
 ["http://i.imgur.com/kCj3uvC.jpg", "Julianne Moore won Best Actress in a Leading Role for her role in Still Alice."],
 ["http://i.imgur.com/OJq9hq1.jpg", "J K Simmons won Best Actor in a Supporting Role for his role in Whiplash."],
 ["http://i.imgur.com/qZ4XnIJ.jpg", "Patricia Arguette won Best Actress in a Supporting Role for her role in Boyhood."],
 ["http://i.imgur.com/QTGeTJ6.jpg?1","Big Hero 6 won Best Animated Feature Film."]
];

var i = 0;

function setComic() {
    console.log(img[i]);
    document.getElementById("comic").src = img[i][0];
    document.getElementById("num").textContent = i+1;
    document.getElementById("title").textContent = img[i][1];
}

setComic();

function prev() {
    i--;
    if (i <= 0) document.getElementById("prev").setAttribute('disabled', true);
    else document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
    setComic();
    console.log(i);
}

function next() {
    i++;
    if (i >= img.length - 1) document.getElementById("next").disabled = true;
    else document.getElementById("prev").disabled = false;
    setComic();
    console.log(i);
}
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zgcd736q/3/)!

I wanted to put the buttons both above and below the picture. So, I did and I replaced the next/prev id with classes and used the `document.getElementsByClass()` thing but it isn't working as I imagined. ([code here](http://jsfiddle.net/zgcd736q/11/)). And that's just the tip of the iceberg.

My questions are as follows:

1. How can I make my code more efficient and effective?
2. How can I make loading of images better for slow connections?
3. Any good advice for making the thing I want to make; resources, tips, etc. etc.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask for. Please clarify your question so that it is a simple problem statement and include only relevant code in reproducing the problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: `getElementsByClass()` gives an array of elements, not a single element.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Oh! So, no way to save lines of code?

Comment: @zzzzBov: Ok, i understand. I've spelled it out. Now, undownvote this. My account can't take any more hits.

Comment: @Nik - `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, whereas `getElementById` returns a single element. So, looking at your last link, labeled `code here`, you need to index the 0th element of the arrays on lines 41, 42, 49 and 50. - E.g `document.getElementsByClassName("prev").disabled = true;` should be `document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0].disabled = true;` and the same for the other 3.

Comment: @enhzflep: Then, I'd have to do `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[1]` things as well right? I used the classes thing to avoid repeating code. Otherwise I could have left it as id's and given them names like next1, next2, prev1, prev2. I feel like I'm overcomplicating somethin very simple.

Comment: @Nik, I appreciate the enthusiasm, but please try to keep it to one question per question. The questions you're asking are too broad, to be answerable. I think at this point you should review [the StackOverflow help center article on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you're really just after a code review, then please post on [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @zzzzBov: Ouch, then sorry I guess. Can you, then, please *migrate* this to the right place? I just want answers. All I actually wanted was another coder's perspective on doing this simple problem (of making the gallery) I want to see how others do it. Are you sure, this isn't the right place?

Comment: As long and only if the code works as you intend, it would make a good post for Code Review to see how it can be improved. Make sure you include all the code to be reviewed in your question.

Comment: @nik - yep, pretty much. You can simplify it with helper functions though. I'll add the way I'd probably approach it - though will only use naive logic for enabling/disabling buttons (you need to handle both sorts of buttons in response to a click on either type - otherwise the prev buttons will stay disabled, and the next buttons will be locked in the disabled state if you reach the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach. I've added it, rather than simply let the question fall-through to code-review, since it failed to enable/disable the buttons correctly - you may see my comment above for more info.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
var img = [
    ["http://i.imgur.com/B1YclC5.jpg", "Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance) won Best Picture."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/XjAdinX.jpg", "Eddie Redmayne won Best Actor in a Leading Role for his role in The Theory of Everything."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/kCj3uvC.jpg", "Julianne Moore won Best Actress in a Leading Role for her role in Still Alice."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/OJq9hq1.jpg", "J K Simmons won Best Actor in a Supporting Role for his role in Whiplash."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/qZ4XnIJ.jpg", "Patricia Arguette won Best Actress in a Supporting Role for her role in Boyhood."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/QTGeTJ6.jpg?1", "Big Hero 6 won Best Animated Feature Film."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/sYXnpMC.jpg", "Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance) won Best Cinematography."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/I0necik.jpg", "The Grand Budapest Hotel won Best Costume Design."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/WKoIcqp.jpg", "Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance) won Best Directing."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/FAOxXO4.jpg", "CitizenFour won Best Documentary Feature."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/7jWMv2d.jpg", "Crisis Hotline: Veterans Press 1 won Best Documentary Short Subject."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/WMxECgv.jpg", "Whiplash won Best Film Editing"],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/igS4Vmh.jpg", "Ida won Best Foreign Language Film."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/6PxTKRo.jpg", "The Grand Budapest Hotel won Best Makeup and Hairstyling."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/H83ss3z.jpg", "The Grand Budapest Hotel won Best Original Score."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/pD5LG2o.jpg", "Glory from the film Selma won Best Original Song."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/7vJYuKI.jpg", "The Grand Budapest Hotel won Best Production Design."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/Xpe3tVC.jpg", "Feast won Best Animated Short Film."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/OIe1PGe.png", "American Sniper won Best Sound Editing."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/PvqfxQe.jpg", "Whiplash won Best Sound Mixing."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/2Z4jjz7.jpg", "Interstellar won Best Visual Effects."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/AOciJZ2.jpg", "The Imitation Game won Best Adapted Screenplay."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/jAWd8MK.jpg", "Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance) won Best Original Screenplay."],
    ["http://i.imgur.com/sJM5sw2.jpg", "Cat tax."]
];

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function byId(elemId){return document.getElementById(elemId);}
function allByClass(className){return document.getElementsByClassName(className);}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func){for (var i=0, n=nodeList.length; i<n; i++) func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList); }

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    var prevBtns = allByClass('prevBtn');
    var nextBtns = allByClass('nextBtn');
    forEachNode(prevBtns, function(elem, index, list) { elem.addEventListener('click', onPrevBtnClick, false); } );
    forEachNode(nextBtns, function(elem, index, list) { elem.addEventListener('click', onNextBtnClick, false); } );
    setComic();
}


var curImgIndex = 0;

function setComic()
{
    console.log(img[curImgIndex]);
    document.getElementById("comic").src = img[curImgIndex][0];
    document.getElementById("num").textContent = curImgIndex + 1;
    document.getElementById("title").textContent = img[curImgIndex][1];
}

function enableButtons(className, isEnabled)
{
    var btnList = allByClass(className);
    forEachNode(btnList, nodeFunc);

    function nodeFunc(elem, index, list)
    {
        elem.disabled = !isEnabled;
    }
}

function onPrevBtnClick()
{
    --curImgIndex;
    if (curImgIndex < 1)
        enableButtons('prevBtn', false);
    else 
        enableButtons('prevBtn', true);

    enableButtons('nextBtn', true);
    setComic();
    console.log(curImgIndex);
}

function onNextBtnClick() 
{
    ++curImgIndex;
    if (curImgIndex > img.length - 2)
        enableButtons('nextBtn', false);
    else 
        enableButtons('nextBtn', true);

    enableButtons('prevBtn', true);
    setComic();
    console.log(curImgIndex);
}
</script>
<style>
img {
    height:250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oscars 2015</h1>

    <!--Top Controls-->
    <button class="prevBtn" disabled>PREVIOUS</button>
    <button class="nextBtn">NEXT</button>

    <h3>(<span id="num">#</span>) <span id='title'>title</span></h3>

    <img id="comic" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <!--Bottom Controls-->
    <button class="prevBtn" disabled>PREVIOUS</button>
    <button class="nextBtn">NEXT</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the answer I needed! Thank you so so so very very much!! :D Omg, this is beautiful :)

Comment: @Nik - you're most welcome. We all stand on the shoulders of those that came before us. Hopefully I can swing-by some day and borrow a cup of sugar myself. :p

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of css for this, and keep your html/jquery to a minimum.

Notice how I've kept the jquery simple, and extracted the `src` attribute from the img tag down the left hand side, and then used this as my background for my `.big` image? That way, I'm keeping requests to a minimum by using the image already there

```js
$('.sidepanel img').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).attr("src");
  $('.gallery .big').css("background", "url(" + val + ")").css("background-size", "100% 100%");
});
```

```css
.sidepanel {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sidepanel img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.gallery .big {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="sidepanel">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/150" />
  </div>
  <div class="big"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. Have you never read **manga** online? I was expecting something in that form. This makes a nice clean little gallery but still not what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Nik: With the amount of programming I do, I don't get time to read manga unfortunately.

Comment: :D hehe, the form I describe is simply a next/prev button image gallery with some cms behind it that I'm not fully aware of.

Comment: @Nik: That's probably done via something completely different. Looking at the site's html when changing page, ou can see the url changing. That's suggesting either that they're different pages altogether, or you might want to look into ajax requests instead.

Comment: Sounds unnecessarily messy. That's why opted to start from level scratch.  There has to be an effective JS solution to this, don't you think?

Comment: @Nik: And hence why your question isn't getting many answers. I'm not saying necessarily that's *why*, but it's a big hindrance. But this is how I would work it. (keeping it simple). You could always 'hide' the side bar, and loop through the child elements via a button?

Comment: :D That's actually a pretty neat solution. I'll consider it. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for each image to have its own array, for example, you can just use the `split(', ')` feature.

Also, I added a 'change image' function that receives parameters so you end up using less code.

```
var images = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/B1YclC5.jpg, description0, alt0',
    'http://i.imgur.com/XjAdinX.jpg, description1, alt1',
    'http://i.imgur.com/kCj3uvC.jpg, description2, alt2',
    'http://i.imgur.com/OJq9hq1.jpg, description3, alt3'],
    max = parseInt(images.length - 1),
    curr = 0;

function display(a, b, c) {
    img = document.getElementById('myImage');
    img.src = a;
    img.setAttribute('alt', b);
    document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML = c;
}

function next() {
    if (curr < max) {
        curr += 1;
        arr = images[curr].split(', ');
        path = arr[0];
        desc = arr[2];
        alt = arr[1];
        display(path, desc, alt);
    }
}

function prev() {
    if (curr > 0) {
        curr -= 1;
        arr = images[curr].split(', ');
        path = arr[0];
        desc = arr[2];
        alt = arr[1];
        display(path, desc, alt);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/p4utrd7v/